# How to get a list of months and year between two dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date

I have to get the list of months and year in between my dates. Currently it only returns month and year for dates that has data associated with it.

for example my dates is between: `'8'+'/1'+'/'+'2015' and DATEADD(mm, 15, '8'+'/1'+'/'+'2016'`

It only prints out: May2016, June2016, July2016, Auguest2016, September2016

I want it to print out all of the months and year in between. Here is my sql queries:

```
select d.id_base as case_id, 
    c.C_LAST_ACTION AS Docketed,
    c.C_CASE_TYPE AS caseType,
    ct.C_NAME As caseName, 
    ct.C_DESCRIPTION AS caseNameDescription,
   case when d.c_mod_decision_id is not null then '' else  DATENAME(mm, d.c_issue_date) + DATENAME(yyyy, d.c_issue_date)  end as display
from t_case_decision d JOIN T_CASE_INPUT c on c.id = d.id_base JOIN T_CASE_TYPE ct on C_CASE_TYPE = ct.id 
where cast(d.c_issue_date AS date) BETWEEN '8'+'/1'+'/'+'2015' and DATEADD(mm, 15, '8'+'/1'+'/'+'2016')
```

Comment: `'8'+'/1'+'/'+'2015'`, huh?  That is really strange.  Your syntax is so clearly SQL Server that I modified the question to reflecct this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff currently i am trying to get all the data starting that month to 15 months out. I need to print out all of the months and year in between even if the month has no data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff not sure if that makes any sense for you.

Comment: Uhmm, do you really need to concatenate the values of month, date and year?

Comment: @L.Herrera yes because i am using the same queries to build a report in ireport which shows Month+Year

Comment: @ReazurRahman: that doesn't explain why your strings need to look like that.

Comment: @L.Herrera the reason why the string looks like that is because the previous report that i am implementing this to looks the same i know it's weird but thats how it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to accomplish, a recursive CTE might help. Here's a quick example of what you can do. The CTE will expand out into a list of dates, which you can then use as the base for your query.

The contents of the TargetData CTE may need to be adjusted, as I don't have a complete picture of your data structure.

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE = '1/1/2015';
DECLARE @endDate DATE = '7/31/2016';

-- Recursive CTE to generate a list of months within the date range:
WITH Months AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(D, -(DAY(@startDate)) + 1, @startDate)) [MonthDate]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(M, 1, MonthDate)
    FROM Months
    WHERE MonthDate <= DATEADD(M, -1, @endDate)
),
TargetData AS (
    -- This is a slightly modified version of the original query:
    select
        d.id_base as case_id, 
        c.C_LAST_ACTION AS Docketed,
        c.C_CASE_TYPE AS caseType,
        ct.C_NAME As caseName, 
        ct.C_DESCRIPTION AS caseNameDescription,
        case when d.c_mod_decision_id is not null then '' else  DATENAME(mm, d.c_issue_date) + DATENAME(yyyy, d.c_issue_date)  end as display,
        -- Return the "MonthDate" so that it can be left joined to the Months table:
        DATEADD(D, -(DAY(d.c_issue_date)) + 1, d.c_issue_date) [MonthDate]
    from t_case_decision d JOIN T_CASE_INPUT c on c.id = d.id_base JOIN T_CASE_TYPE ct on C_CASE_TYPE = ct.id 
    where cast(d.c_issue_date AS date) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
)
SELECT
    m.MonthDate,
    DATENAME(mm, m.MonthDate) + DATENAME(yyyy, m.MonthDate),
    td.*
FROM Months m
    LEFT JOIN TargetData td ON td.MonthDate = m.MonthDate;
```

Comment: Note that this will only work in SQL Server 2005 and later.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without creating the table.

Comment: @ReazurRahman, I updated the example to incorporate your original query instead of the temp table. The temp table in the original example was meant to make it a bit more generic, but was probably a little confusing.

Comment: Hey, with this if i wanted to go back 15 months not go forward how would i do that. I tried to do month date is greater than or equal to that didn't work for me

Comment: @ReazurRahman, apologies, but I'm not sure if I understand your question. To adjust the range of data returned by the query, you should just be able to adjust the `@startDate` and `@endDate` variables. Does that help?

Comment: yup took care of that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, create a [numbers table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable)

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers(N INT)

insert into Numbers(N)
select top 1000000 row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
from   master..spt_values t1 
       cross join master..spt_values t2
```

then use `DATEADD` to list dates between desired values, like this

```
declare @iniDate as date     
set @iniDate='20150801'  

select dateadd(MONTH,N,@iniDate) dates
from Numbers 
where N<15 order by N
```

These returns dates from @iniDate up to 15 months later

**EDIT:** try this, I don't have sql right now

```
select datename(mm, dateadd(MONTH,N,@iniDate))+datename(yyyy ,dateadd(MONTH,N,@iniDate)) display
from ( select top 15row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
from   master..spt_values t1 
       cross join master..spt_values t2) numbers right join (

    select d.id_base as case_id, 
        c.C_LAST_ACTION AS Docketed,
        c.C_CASE_TYPE AS caseType,
        ct.C_NAME As caseName, 
        ct.C_DESCRIPTION AS caseNameDescription,
       case when d.c_mod_decision_id is not null then '' else  DATENAME(mm, d.c_issue_date) + DATENAME(yyyy, d.c_issue_date)  end as display
    from t_case_decision d JOIN T_CASE_INPUT c on c.id = d.id_base JOIN T_CASE_TYPE ct on C_CASE_TYPE = ct.id 
    where cast(d.c_issue_date AS date) BETWEEN '8'+'/1'+'/'+'2015' and DATEADD(mm, 15, '8'+'/1'+'/'+'2016') 
    sql-server
    ) qq
on datename(mm, dateadd(MONTH,N,@iniDate))+datename(yyyy ,dateadd(MONTH,N,@iniDate)) = qq.display

where N<15 order by N
```

Comment: This won't work for me i am trying to use the same queries to build a report in ireport i tried using DATEADD(mm, 15, '8'+'/1'+'/'+'2016') <= 15 but i get an error in sql server saying "incorrect syntax near <="

Comment: @ReazurRahman not sure about your date string, but try this as my exaple try to show `DATEADD(month, N, '8'+'/1'+'/'+'2016')` joining numbers table and `WHERE numbers.N<15`

Comment: @ReazurRahman I just read again, you said `It only prints out: May2016, June2016, July2016, Auguest2016, September2016

I want it to print out all of the months and year in between. Here is my sql queries:` Is it posible that you only have data for only those dates?

Comment: Yes the data is only available for those month but i want to be able to print out all the months whether it has data or no data at all.

Comment: @ReazurRahman See my edit, maybe it won't compile, just work with it. Let me know how it goes

Comment: Is there a way to do this without creating the table?

Comment: seems like the edited version still uses the table. For my job complication i can not create a table to create the dates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join on primary keys between tables, I haven't seen a between statement with that syntax. So I suggest trying the following:

```
SELECT d.id_base as case_id, c.C_LAST_ACTION AS 'Docketed',c.C_CASE_TYPE AScaseType,ct.C_NAME As 'caseName', ct.C_DESCRIPTION AS 'caseNameDescription'
,CASE 
WHEN d.c_mod_decision_id is not null THEN '' AS 'null_val'
ELSE  CONCAT(YEAR(d.c_issue_dateDATENAME), MONTH(d.c_issue_date))
END AS 'display'

FROM t_case_decision d INNER JOIN T_CASE_INPUT c on c.id = d.id_base 
INNER JOIN T_CASE_TYPE ct on c.id = ct.id 

WHERE CONVERT(DATE,d.c_issue_date) BETWEEN '08/01/2015' 
AND '08/01/2016';
```

I hope this helps or points you in the right direction :)

Comment: This is not working. Like i said i need data for 15 months from the starting month which is 08/01/2015 and i need all of the month and year in between those months. What you just did gives me the same result i was getting before.

Comment: I figured you would be able to adjust around my example to fit your needs....You need to add a case statement like: case WHEN MONTH(d.c_issue_date) = 1 THEN 'January'...do that for each month, then in your select statement add YEAR(d.c_issue_date), add the rest of the data you need in the select statement, WHERE d.c_issue_date BETWEEN '08/01/2015' AND DATEADD(MONTH, 15, '08/01/2015') GROUP BY YEAR(d.c_issue_date), MONTH(d.c_issue_date) etc..., ORDER BY d.c_issue_date DESC etc...; Now accept challenges and code away, can't do all your work for you